# saccharides is just another name of (or FOR?) carbohydrate?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the correct option of the two next options?

1) saccharides is just another name of OF carbohydrate?

2) saccharides is just another name FOR? carbohydrate?

Comment: Are you just trying to tell if "of" or "for" is correct, or are you also asking if the underlying "saccharides = carbohydrates" claim is right?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, either "of" or "for" would work.  Either way, it leaves open the possibility there might be other synonyms.  Using "of" subtly implies that "saccharides" belongs to "carbohydrates"; that it is one of its names. Using "for" subtly implies that "saccharides" is an acceptable substitute name.  IMHO, there is not a significant difference between these two,

Although these terms are used differently by physicists, chemists, and nutritionists, I think I have noticed usage of "saccharides" in nutrition to refer primarily to carbohydrates that humans can convert into energy —sugars and starches (monosaccharides, disaccharides, oligosaccharides and polysaccharides)—as contrasted with, say, aspartame, saccharine,  sucralose, or the cellulose found in wood (a polysaccharide which humans cannot metabolize, and which until quite recently was not added to human "food").